# Set the text file to read in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am testing out a file reader for one of my html projects. I want the JavaScript program to read a particular file immediately, instead of the file being selected by the user (in this case, me). I have the p tag and the id of the tag as 'file'. When I run the program in my browser (Safari), I get the error message

```
TypeError: Argument 1 ('blob') to FileReader.readAsText must be an instance of Blob
```

I have been looking all over the internet to find a solution, but I just can't find anything. I was thinking of doing my program with python and then inserting it into my webpage with trinket.io's iframe tag. But then I sort of gave up on that idea. Here is the code:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
var fileToRead = "quotes.txt";

// attach event, that will be fired, when read is end
reader.addEventListener("loadend", function() {
  document.getElementById('file').innerText = reader.result;
});

reader.readAsText(fileToRead);
```

I would like the output of this program to show the contents of the text file, yet when I run it in my browser it gives me a blank screen. I hope there is a solution out there.

Comment: `FileReader` `.readAs<DataURL,Text,Blob,ArrayBuffer>(<Blob>)` expects `Blob` as parameter passed, as the error message states. See [File API](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/).  Is `"quotes.txt"` a local or remote file?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, you can't just go around loading random files of the user :)  Imagine what could happen if that were possible.

Comment: I am loading a file locally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The FileReader expects a blob - which is a file-like object. It can be a blob stored in the memory or a reference to a file. **For security reasons, it doesn't work with file names - you can't simply read an arbitrary file from the user's file system without his consent.**

To achieve it with the user's consent, keep reading below.

You'll need the user to use a file input to explicitly select a file. Once a file is selected, the input will trigger an event with a FileList, containing references to the selected files. The file references can then be used in the FileReader to read their contents.

Here's a working example:

```js
  fileInput.addEventListener("change", onFileChanged)
  
  function onFileChanged(event) {
    const fileList = event.target.files
    fileText.value = ""

    if (fileList.length === 0) {
      console.log("No file selected, please select one!")
      return
    }
    
    if (fileList.length > 1) {
      console.log("Too many files selected, please select only one!")
      return
    }
    
    // destruct first entry of fileList, equivalent to `const file = fileList[0]`
    const [file] = fileList
    
    // you can validate what type of file you accept
    if (file.type !== "text/plain") {
      console.log("Only text files are supported!")
      return
    }

    console.log("Reading file", file.name)
    readFile(file, printText)
  }
  
  function readFile(file, callback) {
    if (typeof callback !== "function") {
      throw new Error("Please supply a callback function to handle the read text!")
    }
    const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
      callback(reader.result)
    })
    return reader.readAsText(file)
  }
  
  function printText(text) {
    fileText.value = text
  }
```

```html
<input id="fileInput" type="file"/>

<div>
  <textarea id="fileText" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>
```